# Вопрос по многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Я в отдельном потоке создаю экземпляр класса, и *передаю в новый поток метод из новосозданного экземпляра класса*.

Т.е. главный поток создал 1 поток, который вызвал 2ой поток.

1. Сможет ли в такой случае последний (2 поток) успешно закрыться и освободить ресурсы?
2. Если передать во второй поток объект, созданный в Главном потоке, то закроется ли поток 2?

Comment: стоит добавить пример кода

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Система не знает, где создан объект, ей всё равно. Поэтому независимо от того, какие объекты создал поток, этот поток может завершиться.

   Но! Поток будет завершён тогда и только тогда, когда его ThreadProc добежит до конца. (Ну или если это главный поток, то функция `Main`. Или если это фоновый поток, то когда приложение начнёт завершаться.) То, когда именно поток умрёт, не зависит [напрямую] от того, какие объекты он создал.
2. То же самое. То, будет ли завершён поток, и когда именно, не зависит от того, работает ли код данного потока с объектом. Когда код ThreadProc добежит до конца, поток окончит работу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. А как тогда быть с утечкой памяти?
Когда поток по каким-то причинам не закрывается. Выходит, что из-за какого-то объекта, который используется, он не может закрыться?

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Пожалуйста! // Не, утечка памяти не может привести к незакрытию потока. То, что поток не завершается, означает, что в нём бежит какой-то код. Ищите, чем занимается этот поток.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: А как можно узнать, что поток отработал, т.е закрылся?

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Ну, смотря какие у вас есть инструменты. Например, в Visual Studio вы видите сообщение в окне Output, когда поток заканчивает работу. Или если ThreadProc в ваших руках, вы можете написать что-нибудь в консоль или лог (`new Thread(() => { DoSomeWork(); Console.WriteLine("Worker thread finished"); }).Start()`. Или в режиме приостановки выполнения в Visual Studio вы можете глянуть в окошко Threads, и открыть текущий call stack этого потока. И т. д.

Comment: спасибо, а программно узнать это нельзя?
например, используя пул потоков, а не отдельные потоки

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Ну например [`t.IsAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Вам придётся при этом запомнить объект `Thread` в какой-нибудь переменной.

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Подождите, а с пулом потоков ситуация вообще другая. Там потоки не умирают никогда! Они выполняют задания одно за другим. Когда одно задание отработало, поток получает следующее и работает над ним. Так что с пулом всё по-другому. Поток из пула в принципе не должен умирать.

Comment: Спасибо! К стати ,я пробую писать код по Вашему образцу:
<pre> new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Listen;
                    WriteLog(">>Listen thread is finished! <<<");
                }).Start();
<code>
но получаю ошибку: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут ошибка?

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Вероятно, нужно `Listen()`?

Comment: Да, так работает, простите(

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Вот и хорошо. Будем считать опечаткой. :)

Answer (score 5):

Создаваемые экземпляры объектов и потоки -- вещи ортогональные. Объекты вы создаете в памяти, потоки -- обращаются к этой памяти. При этом в каком потоке какой объект был создан -- неважно, за исключением двух случаев:

- с UI контролами можно работать только в том же потоке, в котором они
  были созданы
- с некоторыми COM-компонентам можно работать только в том же
  потоке/том же контексте, в котором они были созданы

На "успешность закрытия" потока объекты в любом случае не влияют.